# Python-telegram-bot. Как назначить текст на кнопке так , чтобы на кнопке допустим было "Меню" , но при нажатии отправлялось "/start,"?

Tags: python, telegram, бот

markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True,row_width = 2)

```
    buttons = ["Главное меню",
               "Начать охоту"]                           
    markup.add(*buttons)
    
    mess = "<b>Проведём краткий инструктаж:  Вам нужно попробовать опознать призрака по букве до того как он вас убьёт.Удачи!  </b>" 
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,mess,parse_mode = "html",reply_markup=markup)
```

Answer (score 0):

Никак, так как согласно документации Telegram пользователю отправляется текст кнопки. Не идеально, но можно сделать так:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def start(message):
    if(message.text == "/start" or message.text == "Главное меню"):
        #какие-то действия
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я уже перешёл на аиограм , и решил эту проблему фильтром